# Как открыть файл, который находится на сервере?

Tags: c#

```
Process.Start("\\server\\C\\WinAsm\\WinAsm.exe");
```

Такой способ пишет, что файл не найден.

Можно как-нибудь процесс так запустить?

Comment: "\\\\server\\C$\\WinAsm\\WinAsm.exe"

Comment: или воспользоваться ссылкой )

Answer (score 2):

```
Process.Start("\\server\\C\\WinAsm\\WinAsm.exe");
```

или же

```
Process.Start(@"\server\C\WinAsm\WinAsm.exe");
```

является запуском программы по относительному пути к активной дитектории программы. Скорее всего активной директорией будет являтся папка самой программы.

Что бы запустить программу с сервера нужно доавить еще один слеш в пути что бы вышло

```
Process.Start("\\\\server\\C\\WinAsm\\WinAsm.exe");
```

или

```
Process.Start(@"\\server\C\WinAsm\WinAsm.exe");
```